# WP7 emulator not working after WP8 sdk

Tags: emulation, windows-phone-8

So I wanted to debug using the WP 7.1 emulator option but can't make the emulator to start, it says is doing a complete OS boot, then WP logo and sits there forever

This happened after installing WP8 SDK

Anyone has solved this?

Comment: I had the same issue after installing the WP8 SDK, and it works again now. I'm not sure what has changed, so I would suggest starting by a reboot. Also, try waiting a few minutes while the emulator is booting, looks like it becomes way slower after the installation of the WP8 SDK.

Comment: I see, so maybe it's a minor issue, in any case the WP8 emulator is working fine, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please uninstall the WP7 SDK prior to installing the WP8 SDK. The WP8 SDK includes support for WP7 applications.

The WP8 SDK emulator is a Hyper-V powered emulator, and is quite different from WP7.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, the emulator is not getting past the "Starting Windows Phone OS" step. During previous boot, it was asking me about hardware supported virtualization in BIOS, but my PC doesn't have that option. Any ideas?

Comment: If your PC don't have [SLAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Level_Address_Translation) support, then you can't use the Hyper-V, and Windows Phone 8 SDK, sorry.

Comment: I can't tell. I had both installed on the same machine.